# Can app have multiple paths for NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

In any scenario can app have multiple paths in `NSArray` when accessing `NSDocumentDirectory` using following code :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

I am just curious about thing..can you all share your experience with me?

Comment: not getting you question properly!!!

Comment: @KetanParmar: right now when you are using above code you will get one path in NSArray..my question is do you any scenario when above result return multiple path in NSArray?

Answer (score 1):

Strictly spoken you can get *multiple* paths because you can pass *multiple* domains.

If you pass a *single* domain you get an array containing a *single* path.

However Apple recommends not to use this function anymore.

From the documentation:

> You should consider using the `NSFileManager` methods `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` and `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` which return URLs, which are the preferred format.

Comment: Can you guide me in deep why not to use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains method?

Comment: This is a general recommendation of Apple to prefer the URL related over the path related API and to use methods of Cocoa classes rather than Foundation C-functions.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html#.. you will get clear than we can use both methods..just for your information.

Comment: Of course you can but *You should consider using...* is an indicator to prefer the URL related API, also because `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is not able to create a missing directory on demand.

Answer (score 0):

No this will always return one path for documentDirectory!!

It may vary as per different kind of directory like,

```
 NSString *path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
```

above line will give temp directory's path.

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

above array have also one path but this is path of `NSDocumentationDirectory`.

[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1414224-nssearchpathfordirectoriesindoma?language=objc) Creates a list of path strings for the specified directories in the specified domains. The list is in the order in which you should search the directories.

You can get content or sub directory of document directory or any directory like,

```
  NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSAllDomainsMask, YES);

NSArray *contentOfDocDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathArr[0] error:nil];

NSLog(@"content of document directory : %@",contentOfDocDirectory);
```